# Not Lebesgue Integrable

Tags: lebesgue-integral

Let g(x) be the function from R to R defined by
$g(x)= 1$             if $x=0$,
                                             $\frac{\sin x}x$ otherwise.

Define the function $g_n (x)= g(x)$   if $-n < x < n$ and $x=0$ otherwise.

Show that for every n, $g_n$ is integrable on $\mathbb R$.
And that $g_n$ converges to $g$.

Comment: convergence in which sense?

Comment: It just said $g_n$ goes to g

Comment: You have choices: simple convergence? uniform? $L^2$?

Comment: simple convergence or uniform

Comment: I need to prove either or

Answer (score 1):

$
|g_n(x) - g(x)| \neq 0 \Rightarrow |x|\ge n
$
so
$$
\sup_x |g_n(x) - g(x)| = \sup_{|x|\ge n} \frac{|\sin x|}{|x|}
\le \frac 1n
$$
then $g_n\to g$ and the convergence is uniform.

As far as the integrability is concerned, as $g_n$ is bounded and non zero on a bounded interval, it is Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: why g_n -g not 0????

Comment: to locate where is the difference takes the biggest value.

Comment: since g is not integrable, why does this not violate Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem?

Comment: why should this violate the TDC?

Comment: Because g_n goes to g but g is not integrable

Comment: yes, but there is no domination hypothesis.

Comment: but we have |g_n| is bounded

Comment: the domination hypothesis is: $\exists G \ \ |g_n|\le G$ and $\int G < \infty$.